# Access individual item in a GridView in Android

Tags: android, gridview, android-view, android-gridview

I am facing issue in accessing individual item inside a gridview. I have a grid view of images. On Long press of individual item I am activating CAB menu with multi mode listener. Inside the listener, I am able to do

```
gridView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

But I am unable to do this and it gives NUll Pointer Exception

```
gridView.getChildAt(position).setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

I have tried this also:

```
ViewGroup gridChild = (ViewGroup) gridView.getChildAt(1);
int childSize = gridChild.getChildCount();
for(int k = 0; k < childSize; k++) {
 if( gridChild.getChildAt(k) instanceof ImageView ) {
      gridChild.getChildAt(k).setVisibility(View.GONE);
 }
}
```

How can I overcome this?

Update:

Inside my Adapter getView() method:

```
 imageview.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener(){
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    overlay.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    imageview.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#f9a49c"));
    return false;
}});
```

What I am trying to do here is, I just want to change the background color onclick. But the color is changing for the last element in the current view. And also that too not staying after press. It just goes off after press.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your adapter's `getView()` method, you should set the view to visible or not, depending on the state the data backing the adapter.

You shouldn't assume that every item has a unique view, adapters typically reuse the views of items that go out of the screen when scrolling.

Comment: Updated the question. What I am trying to do here is, I just want to change the background color onclick. But the color is changing for the last element in the current view. And also that too not staying after press. It just goes off after press.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to notify adapter

```
if( gridChild.getChildAt(k) instanceof ImageView ) {

gridChild.getChildAt(k).setVisibility(View.GONE);

notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```